# How to locate the line where a vim plugin error occurs: "Mapping not found"

Tags: windows, vim

When I open gvim, it gives "Mapping not found" warning.

I found out that the problem is related to the snipmates.vim plugin.

But I can't locate where exactly in snipmates.vim file this error is produced. Is there a way to find out the exact cause?

Note: 
gvim 7.2 runs on Windows XP.

I found a solution advice in [vim mail list](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg04277.html).

```
gvim -V20 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

I run this command from command prompt but it doesn't output anything into the logfile. All the logs are written on the entry screen of gvim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command instead:

```
gvim -V20logfile
```

When gVim comes up, verify that your "Mapping not found" error message has appeared, then exit gVim and search the logfile for the error.